# how can I re-direct to different pages using the same controller ActionResult?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two views using the same ActionResult. There was originally only one view but now there is the need for a second.

The views are - "Index" & "Accepted"
Index

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string status, string message)
    {
        var InboxStatus = InboxStatus.New;

        if (!Enum.TryParse(status, out inboxStatus))
            inboxStatus = InboxStatus.New;

        var model = new InboxModel();
        model.Status = inboxStatus.ToString();

        model.InboxMailCount = GetInboxMailCount();
        model.InboxMailCount.Status = InboxStatus.ToString();

        @ViewBag.Message = message;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Accept

```
       [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Accept(InboxModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var inboxmail = _repo.GetById(model.ID);

            inboxmail.Status = (int)ReferralStatus.Accepted;
            inboxmail.AcceptedByUserId = UserId;
            inboxmail.AcceptenceDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            _uow.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "Accepted Successfully" });
        }

        return View(model.ID.ToString());
    }
```

The ActionResult is called "Declined",
The problem is that the Action Result contains the following...

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Decline(InboxModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var InBox = _repo.GetById(model.ID);

            InBox.Status = (int)ReferralStatus.Declined;
            InBox.DeclinedByUserId = UserId;
            InBox.DeclinedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            _uow.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "Declined Successfully" });
        }

        return Accept(model.ID.ToString());
    }
```

So if the user select's the "Declined" action on either page they will be re-directed to "Index" regardless of them carrying out the action on the "Accepted" view.
Make sense,? I want to re-direct them back to the page they came from.

Please note this is how I am currently re-directing to "Accepted" for different action...

As the lists in Index depend on the "Status" property...
Index view..

ASP.Net MVC 4 using razor 2 views.....any ideas?

Comment: Are you haveing to views in the index action ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, Index acts as my "selected message", then depending on the message status, they appear in a different list such as status = Accepted...I'll update code to show code of the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `ViewBag.ReturnUrl` to store the most recent ActionName in the sequence of operations.

Example:

```
public ActionResult ActionA(){
 ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "ActionA";
 return View();
}

public ActionResult ActionB(){
 ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "ActionB";
 return View();
}

public ActionResult Declined(){
 return RedirectToAction(ViewBag.ReturnUrl);
}
```

Comment: So for example I would place ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "Accepted" with my Accepted Action..? and do the same in Index..

Comment: problem with the following code....ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "Index" , new{ Status = (int)InboxStatus.Accepted};

Comment: that code won't compile. Edit your post so I can see it in its entirety

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cache or save your previous url and then just redirect back to it.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var previousPage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;


        //Yourlogic

        RedirectToAction(previousPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a property in your InboxModel to state your origin.
Then, in your forms you can place a Hidden with that value.

BTW, you are redirecting to Index without passing the Status parameter... am I wrong?

Comment: Your correct, as Index is the mail details, so Index with status 1(accepted mail), and status 2= (sent mail) etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Got it !! Apologies, it was not a straight forward question as there was alot of code to add to the confusion, thanks to all for you time..

Basically save the initial status of the mail at the begining of the action..
As it the status only changes within the action.
At the top of the Accepted ActionResult,

```
 var returnStatus = Mail.Status;
```

Then use that variable in the return....

```
  return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Status = (int)returnStatus, Message = "Mail Successfully added to Sent Listing" });
```